# how to come back main.xml from other xml file

Tags: android

In my application, i used the optionMenu by selecting those options.. Each option will display different Layout xml files and those are have some radio buttons and some are have Text Display. now when user moves to main.xml to other Xml screen that Ex: help.xml after that by pressing the Back button it will going to Mobile Home screen.

If any any body knows this how come back main.xml screen from other (Ex. help.xml) try to give me your valuable idea to overcome this.

Thanks for Reading

Comment: please read and rewrite yout question, it is VERY hard to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that you have separate activities (e.g., from your "main" activity you have the option menu and selecting e.g., help will launch the help activity).

In this case you can use startActivityForResult. When the new activity is finished it creates a bundle that contains results and calls setResult on itself and then call finish() on itself. Now Android will call your main activity's onActivityResult() to inform it that the started activity has finished.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#opennewscreen for further information and other tips on opening new screens.